# Android Studio | Libgdx | Adding Kryonet Library - NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, android-studio, libgdx, kryonet

I am currently working on an Android game and want to implement multiplayer.
So i wanted to use Kryonet:

- I downloaded the library (https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryonet/releases)
- created a libs folder in my core module
- copied the kryonet-2.21-all.jar into it
- and added it as Module in the build.gradle:

  ```
  dependencies {
   compile files('src/libs/kryonet-2.21-all.jar')  }
  ```

In Android Studio it seemed to work, i had access to all imports etc., but when running the app on my device.. it crashed

```
07-16 00:00:44.419  12176-12196/com.cookedapps.robotredemption.android E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 3363
Process: com.cookedapps.robotredemption.android, PID: 12176
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/esotericsoftware/kryonet/Server;
        at com.cookedapps.robotredemption.server.GameServer.<init>(GameServer.java:20)
        at com.cookedapps.robotredemption.states.Play.<init>(Play.java:73)
        at com.cookedapps.robotredemption.handlers.GameStateManager.getState(GameStateManager.java:39)
        at com.cookedapps.robotredemption.handlers.GameStateManager.pushState(GameStateManager.java:49)
        at com.cookedapps.robotredemption.handlers.GameStateManager.<init>(GameStateManager.java:21)
        at com.cookedapps.robotredemption.main.Game.create(Game.java:41)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:241)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1520)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1248)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Server" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.cookedapps.robotredemption.android-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.cookedapps.robotredemption.android-2/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
        at com.cookedapps.robotredemption.server.GameServer.<init>(GameServer.java:20)
        at com.cookedapps.robotredemption.states.Play.<init>(Play.java:73)
        at com.cookedapps.robotredemption.handlers.GameStateManager.getState(GameStateManager.java:39)
        at com.cookedapps.robotredemption.handlers.GameStateManager.pushState(GameStateManager.java:49)
        at com.cookedapps.robotredemption.handlers.GameStateManager.<init>(GameStateManager.java:21)
        at com.cookedapps.robotredemption.main.Game.create(Game.java:41)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:241)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1520)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1248)
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Server
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
        ... 10 more
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

I tried /gradlew clean in cmd and other stuff, but nothing helped.
Please give me a hint im stuck since a few hours with this.. Thank you!

Comment: i just had same problem, the solution is to either copy the jar inside android/libs or inside root build.gradle -> inside android project ->inside dependencies-> `compile fileTree(dir:'../core/libs', include:'*.jars')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I found a solution.** I had a wrong approach.
How to add Kryonet to a libgdx - Android project:

- Go to root build.gradle
- Go to `project(":core")` - `dependencies` and add:

`compile "com.esotericsoftware:kryo:3.0.1"
 compile ("com.esotericsoftware:kryonet:2.22.0-RC1") {
      exclude module : 'kryo'
 }`

- Sync Project with Gradle Files

**The important point is to add Kryonet, exclude Kryo and adding Kryo separately.** Like that you can avoid this exception:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define
```

*I hope i can help someone with this!*

Comment: A DexException has nothing to do with Kryonet, it only means that you have reached the maximum number of methods you can use without turning multidex on. So you could have achieved this by excluding any arbitrary package to make the total size/number of methods smaller

Comment: How to set compile to the latest version ?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you add:

```
dependencies {
 compile files('src/libs/kryonet-2.21-all.jar') 
}
```

in

```
project(":android")
```

in your build.gradle file too, not just the desktop project